# Logstash read json objects

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I am getting log lines that have syslog headers but contain have a json payload. 
Here is a sample log line

```
12704434--user--notice--IP--{"HOSTNAME"--2017-05-31T16:39:15.010396-04:00--{"HOSTNAME":"HOSTNAME","@version":1,"level":"INFO","logger_name":"com.fgfdg.fdgfdgd.chorus.choir.DNSApplication","appName":"chorus-dns","appVersion":"1.0","thread_name":"main","message":"Started DNSApplication in 11.433 seconds (JVM running for 18.936)"}
```

And here is my filter bit ..

```
filter
{
    grok
    {
        match=>["message","%{DATA:syslog_logentry}--%{WORD:syslog_facility}--%{LOGLEVEL:syslog_priority}--%{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_destination}--%{DATA}--%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:datestamp}--\{%{GREEDYDATA:payload}\}"]
        remove_field => ["path"]
    }
    json
    {
        source => "%{payload}"
    }
}
```

I am not seeing the data being broken out into fields in elastic. Is amd I doing the filter wrong? Or do I need something special in input?

Thanks.

Comment: I think your grok pattern needs to end like this `--%{GREEDYDATA:payload}`, i.e. the `{` and `}` need to be captured by the `GREEDYDATA` pattern otherwise the `payload` field won't contain valid JSON data.

Comment: Hey, that was the first thing I tried! I can give it a shot again.. any other suggestions ?

Comment: Seems to be working well in my grok debugger. What do you get with that?

Comment: Hey, what debug are you using? I am reading the file from syslog and I am wondering if the write to syslog is breaking the the log lines in some way...

Comment: http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Hey, I had a look at this, I am able to apply my grok filter and that works fine. I am able to seperate the header from the json object but I am expecting to read the json part and expecting elastic to turn the json object into fields with data. I am wondering how I can test that aspect with the grok debugger. Thanks, Karan.

Comment: How do the documents look like when they land in ES?

Comment: "payload": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }

This is from devtools -> mappings. Payload is the field I use that holds the json data. It just gets written as a string ..

Comment: "payload": "{\"HOSTNAME\":\"34HT943L\",\"@version\":1,\"level\":\"WARN\",\"logger_name\":\"org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor\",\"appName\":\"chorus-dns\",\"appVersion\":\"1.0\",\"thread_name\":\"main\",\"message\":\"Cannot enhance Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.\"}",
This is what the string looks like.